# How can i tell state of a thread?

Tags: c#

I need to know when is this thread finished with whatever is it doing. also have an active timer on background.

note: "scanner" is an recursive function

```
// button click

//timer
timer.Enabled = true;


//thread
System.Threading.ThreadStart start = delegate { scanner(@"c:\", "*.txt;*.html;"); };
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(start);
thread.Start();

-------------


private static long Counter = 0;
private static string scanstatus = string.Empty;
private static void scanner(string folder, string patterns)
{
    // Get the patterns.
    string[] pattern_array = patterns.Split(';');
    foreach (string pattern in pattern_array)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, pattern))
            {
                //trim path
                scanstatus = (fileName.Length > 50) ? "../" + fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 49, 49) : fileName;
                // delay
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                Counter++;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        foreach (string directory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            scanner(directory, patterns);
    }
    catch (System.Exception E)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: To be honest you may want to start with a higher level abstraction such as: [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Using threads gives you fine grained control but requires lots of boilerplate code to solve simple problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the MSDN Article on Thread Synchronization:

[Thread Synchronization (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Pay close attention to the "Synchronization Events and Wait Handles" section

Answer (score 0):

hi use a backgroundworker it allows you to follow the status of work (progress event), completed event and you can cancel it

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    class Program
    {
      static BackgroundWorker _bw;

      static void Main()
      {
        _bw = new BackgroundWorker
        {
          WorkerReportsProgress = true,
          WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

        _bw.RunWorkerAsync ("Hello to worker");

        Console.WriteLine ("Press Enter in the next 5 seconds to cancel");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (_bw.IsBusy) _bw.CancelAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
      }

      static void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20)
        {
          if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
          _bw.ReportProgress (i);
          Thread.Sleep (1000);      // Just for the demo... don't go sleeping
        }                           // for real in pooled threads!

        e.Result = 123;    // This gets passed to RunWorkerCompleted
      }

//here set your scanner work
      static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted (object sender,
                                         RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (e.Cancelled)
          Console.WriteLine ("You canceled!");
        else if (e.Error != null)
          Console.WriteLine ("Worker exception: " + e.Error.ToString());
        else
          Console.WriteLine ("Complete: " + e.Result);      // from DoWork
      }

      static void bw_ProgressChanged (object sender,
                                      ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Reached " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know when the thread finishes, you can do simply something like below:

```
DateTime _startTime=DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan _elapsedTime;


.....

thread.Start();
while(thread.IsAlive)
{
 Thread.Sleep(100);
}


private static void scanner(string folder, string patterns)
{


// do your work here

_elapsedTime=DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime);

}
```

But you need to be more specific about `with whatever is it doing`

Comment: @Power-Mosfet , it was just because you may need the _elapsedTime before you keep on your process and to be notified as exacerbatedexpert stated above comment.